# How to disable the enriched text of the summernote without activating the codeview mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

Good afternoon. What happens that I want to get a text string with HTML tags, but the summernote interprets them and shows the rich text, and what I want is to show the text with tags, but I have not succeeded:

```
var content = '<b>Content</b> and <b>tags</b> and <i>HTML</i>';

//I have tried this:
$('#summernote').summernote('code',content);
$('#summernote').val(content);
```

But the result is this: **Content** and **tags** and *HTML*

*What I want is to copy and paste a text that contains HTML tags, but I do not want the summernote to interpret those tags. What I want, is that the user can see the tags when pasting that text without activating the mode 'code view'*

```js
var content = '<b>Content</b> and <b>tags</b> and <i>HTML</i>';

//Initialize the summernote
$('#summernote').summernote({
  height: 200
});

$('#summernote').summernote('code',content);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.js"></script>

<div id="summernote">

</div>
```

Comment: take a look to [pre tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

Comment: Change settings.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom toolbar with Summernote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812825/custom-toolbar-with-summernote)

Comment: I checked the file settings.js I think that could be the solution. @Moob

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. I do not know if the text enrichment of the summernote can be disabled in some way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summernote WYSIWYG : set code view as default view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976083/summernote-wysiwyg-set-code-view-as-default-view)

Comment: Jummm .. No @imvain2. I already tried to load the codeview by default, but when I did that, another problem was generated, which I already post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198929/how-to-insert-nuggett-when-the-codeview-mode-is-activated-in-my-editor-wysiwyg

Comment: What I really want is that when copying a text that contains HTML tags from another side, the summernote does not interpret HTML tags, but when you paste the content, treat it as a normal text string and visually see the tags.

Comment: Please clarify *«from another side»*... Be clear about the copy **form**  and **to** and the expected result. -- Voting as *unclear* for now...

Comment: What I want is to copy and paste a text that contains HTML tags, but I do not want the summernote to interpret those tags. What I want, is that the user can see the tags when pasting that text without activating the mode 'code view'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, I have managed to resolve the issue.

My goal was that at the moment of pasting content with HTML from an external source (word), the Summernote would not interpret the labels and if it would show me a string showing me the tags.

Something like this:

"Text with **HTML** and *hide* tags" ==> "<p>Text with <b>HTML</b> and <i>hide</i> tags</p><br>"

***The solution was:***

1. Get the content that was copied and pasted

   ```
   let contentPasted = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
   ```
2. Replace the symbols (**<** and **>**) with (**& lt**; and **& gt;**)

   ```
   let finalContent = contentPasted.replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/</g,'&lt;')
   ```

And with this, it was enough for the HTML code not to be interpreted:

[image]

[image]